# Selecting color to mark means on boxplot with stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

So there's several useful pages up about marking means on boxplots with multiple series; but even with those I'm having an issue where I can't select a color for the points and still show the two different means. I can do this:

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- subset(mpg,class=="compact"|class=="midsize")
ggplot(d,aes(drv,hwy,color=class)) + geom_boxplot() + scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","orange")) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean,size=.5,shape=5,position=position_dodge(width=.75))
```

And that gives me the two different means, but they're the same color as the boxplots themselves and so not the best to look at.

[image: First attempt at boxplot, means distinguished]

So I add a color specification into the code:

```
ggplot(d,aes(drv,hwy,color=class)) + geom_boxplot() + scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","orange")) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean,size=.5,color="black",shape=5,position=position_dodge(width=.75))
```

But then it's only showing the one mean.

[image: second attempt, means not distinguished]

So what am I missing here to get both a specified color and the multiple means being marked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you overwrite the colour aesthetic in `stat_summary()` you also lose
the grouping information. You need to bring it back explicitly with `aes(group = class)`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

d <- subset(mpg, class == "compact" | class == "midsize")

ggplot(d, aes(drv, hwy, color = class)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(
    aes(group = class),
    colour = "black",
    fun = mean,
    size = .5,
    shape = 5,
    position = position_dodge(width = .75)
  )
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

[image]

Comment: This did just the trick! I figured I could have changed color to fill as suggested above and gotten it to work, but this gives me the option to still use color. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Using `fill` to color the box, and `color` for `stat_summary` you get the desired output.

```
ggplot(d,aes(drv,hwy, fill=class)) + geom_boxplot() + scale_fill_manual(values=c("cyan","orange")) +
    stat_summary(fun=mean,size=.5, color="red", 
                 shape=5,position=position_dodge(width=.75))
```

[image: output]